# Getting account disabled error when deploying an App Engine Flexible project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am getting account disabled error when deploying a Google App Engine Flexible project.

I have been deploying this same code base; the last time I deployed was last week on 12th April 2018.

Nothing has changed - actually, only the source code has changed but not configuration stuff. Right now, this is the message that I get:

```
Pushing us.gcr.io/my-project-name/appengine/default.20180417t135325:latest
The push refers to repository [us.gcr.io/my-project-name/appengine/default.20180417t135325]
b5028d3ca9be: Preparing
9256b580f8a6: Preparing
737f4b4192c4: Preparing
74fd8b113997: Preparing
043a40530eeb: Preparing
9d5362e321f8: Preparing
ed2f56cb7492: Preparing
58f025dfe415: Preparing
21df82f90a72: Preparing
9d5362e321f8: Waiting
ed2f56cb7492: Waiting
58f025dfe415: Waiting
21df82f90a72: Waiting
denied: Account disabled.
```

When I look at activity page on Google console
https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity?project=my-project-name&authuser=2, this is what I see:

```
myemail@mydomain.com failed to execute google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1.CloudBuild.CreateBuild on builds
April 17, 2018 at 12:12:35 PM GMT+3
User
myemail@mydomain.com
Resource name
projects/my-project-name/builds
Error message
Failed precondition (HTTP 400): FAILED_PRECONDITION
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Does checking your billing status in the console show anything useful?

Comment: Thanks @DaveW.Smith it was a billing issue, a colleague updated the billing information and I can now deploy. I think the message from google is not clear, the probably should say 'account disabled due to billing '

Comment: You should create an answer and Accept it so people know this is solved.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks , doing that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a billing issue, a colleague updated the billing information and I can now deploy. I think the message from google is not clear, the probably should say 'account disabled due to billing.

The suggestion from @DaveW.Smith was very helpful.